# Lean4: Proving that `(xs = ys) = (reverse xs = reverse ys)`

Tags: logic, coq, proof, theorem-proving, lean

Intuitively stating that `xs` is equal to `ys` is the same as saying that the respective reverse lists are equal to each other.

I'm currently learning Lean 4 and so I set myself the following exercise. I want to prove the following theorem in Lean 4:

```
theorem rev_eq (xs ys : List α) : (xs = ys) = (reverse xs = reverse ys)
```

However, I am not sure, whether this theorem can actually be proven in Lean 4. If not, why can it not be proven?

The closest I could get so far is proving the claim under the assumption that `xs = ys`:

```
theorem rev_eq' (xs ys : List α) :
  xs = ys -> (xs = ys) = (reverse xs = reverse ys) := by
  intros h
  rw [h]
  simp
```

Maybe, if one could prove that the claim also holds if one assumes that `xs` is not equal to `ys`, then the original theorem would follow. I got stuck on that route as well though.

Any ideas?

Comment: Note that this theorem is provided in mathlib as [`List.reverse_inj`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Mathlib/Data/List/Basic.html#List.reverse_inj). By convention, we usually state equivalence of propositions using `↔` not `=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Lean, it is usually idiomatic to state the equality of propositions using `Iff`, which is equivalent under the axiom `propext`. From there, `iff` is an inductive type with two sides, one direction that you have proved, and the other direction that follows from induction. (This theorem is still provable without this axiom, fwiw)

But I'd recommend you to do `induction xs` and `induction ys` and then look at the goals. Two should be impossible and Lean should show you they are contradictions (or indeed you'll get a that can be simplified to `false = false`) and two trivially true goals. Make sure to expand the definition of `reverse`.

Answer (score 0):

This property is typically proved by induction. I never used lean but once induction on the list is done then it should be easy. You may need a lemma saying that `(xs = ys) -> xs@l = xs@l` (also by induction I guess, @ stands for list concatenation).

Comment: Sure, induction sounds sensible. I'm just struggling with the fact that I cannot really make any assumptions on the values of `xs` and `ys`. All I seem to be able to do is to construct an equality and then use rewrite rules to manipulate it.

Comment: Well the property is true whatever the value of `xs` and `ys` are. So it is quite expectable that you cannot assume anything about them.